# adding and removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a class and change the image after it is clicked but for some reason it is not working. I think I'm missing out something very basic and simple. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

```
<div class="penguin1" id="remove"></div>
```

```css
.penguin1:hover {
    background-image: url(../media/mound_1_hover.png);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.penguin1:active, .stay {
    background-image:url(../media/penguin_1.png);
}
.penguin1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-image:url(../media/mound_1.png);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This code will run after your page loads
    $("#remove").click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('penguin1').addClass('stay');;
    });
});
```

I want to replace the image in `penguin1` class with image in `penguin:hover`.

Comment: Is the element, remove added dynamically? You should try Delegates `$(selector).on("eventName", function(event){})`

Comment: Your code is working, however the element seems like it disappears as you remove the `.penguin1` class which sets the `width` and `height` properties: https://jsfiddle.net/zp4o0af4/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a width and height to your .stay class:

```
.penguin1:active,
.stay {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats);
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```js
$("#remove").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('penguin1').addClass('stay');;
});
```

```css
.penguin1:hover {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.penguin1:active,
.stay {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats);
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}

.penguin1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/business);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="penguin1" id="remove">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much... i have been cursing myself for being too dumb for javascript!!!

Comment: No problem, you were very close! BTW, don't forget to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```js
$("#remove").click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('penguin1').addClass('stay');;
});
```

```css
.penguin1:hover {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150x150);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.penguin1:active,
.stay {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
}
.penguin1 {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
}
#remove {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="penguin1" id="remove"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, however the element seems like it disappears as you remove the `.penguin1` class which sets the `width` and `height` properties: https://jsfiddle.net/zp4o0af4/

If you want to just keep the `background-image` after clicking, don't remove the original `penguin1` class and use `toggleClass` to set `stay` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#remove").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('stay');
    });
});
```

```css
.penguin1:active,
.penguin1.stay {
    /* background-image: url(../media/penguin_1.png); */
    background-color: #C00;
}

.penguin1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    /* background-image: url(../media/mound_1.png); */
    background-color: #000;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zp4o0af4)

Note the example above is using `background-color` so the effect is viewable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to work fine. You should check if image paths are correct.

**Note** *I have used background so that effect is visible.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // This code will run after your page loads
  $("#remove").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('penguin1').addClass('stay');;
  });
});
```

```css
.penguin1:hover {
  background-image: url(../media/mound_1_hover.png);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.stay{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}

.penguin1:active,
.stay {
  background-image: url(../media/penguin_1.png);
  background:blue;
}
.penguin1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(../media/mound_1.png);
  background:gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="penguin1" id="remove"></div>
```